# What, if any, circuit elements are disallowed downstream of a GFCI?

Tags: electrical, gfci

This was inspired by the "reverse" [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/198898/) .   Is there any switch, protection element, (even a new breaker box) which is not allowed to be installed downstream of a GFCI?

Comment: What do you mean by "a GFCI"?  That's like "a blue".  There's a noun missing.  A GFCI recep? GFCI breaker? GFCI deadfront? GFCI combo device? GFCI device (globally: of any kind)?

Comment: Also, are you caring only about things that'd turn up in an average single family dwelling, or do you want to hear about the exotics as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only restriction would be in a “smart switch” that doesn't have a neutral but uses the ground for a small amount of current I think these are limited to 5 but I would have to check on that to verify the number.